# Automatically resize rows height to fit the highest cell's content

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview and I have set its:

```
AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle : WrapMode = true,
AutoSizeColumnsMode : Fill,
AutoSizeRowsMode: AllCellsExceptHeaders,
ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode : EnableResizing,
ColumnHeadersHeight : 38,
DefaultCellStyle: WrapMode = true,
RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle : WrapMode = true,
RowHeadersWidthSizeMode : EnableResizing,
RowsDefaultCellStyle: WrapMode =  true
```

And here is what I get:

[image]

Notice how these columns:

[image]

doesn't look well, and the content in them is cropped.

But for example, this cell:

[image]

made its row to resize to fit its content size.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

I have figured out the reason why this happening, but not how to fix it. It turned out that the problem was related with DataGridViewComboBox column, while DataGridViewTextBox columns work as expected.

Here is the setup for the first column (which has its data-source set):

[image]

Comment: After setting the grids properties as you have posted, I am unable to reproduce what you describe. The grids rows grow/shrink as expected and no rows chop off data. Is there possibly something else going on after the grid has been initialized?

Comment: @JohnG I would say nothing is happening after initialization when it comes to setting up the datagridview...Maybe something else is actually happening, but obviously I am not aware of what that could be (what can cause this behaviour).

Comment: I agree that something else is going on, are there possibly any special “columns” that are used? I am not sure how that would make a difference, in addition, what is the grid using as a data source (if any)? Again, I am just grabbing at straws here because I would not think either of those items would make a difference in the grids UI row behavior.

Comment: Have you tried… If the grid is not overly complicated and you are setting the grids properties in the “designer”… dump it and create a new one.

Comment: @JohnG I am using Entity Framework, and a gridview is bound to a binding source. Those two columns are standard columns with a lot of text... I could try to delete the gridview and make it again, but I doubt it will help. Still, I could do it and let you know how that went.

Comment: @JohnG I found what the issue was, but I don't know a proper way to solve this. I mean, I could probably think of some workaround ... But I wonder is there a way to solve this, rather than finding workarounds...

Comment: @JohnG Actually, a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49097960/3402095) solved this well. I just added a new property in my model, and then used it to obtain column's data. So, instead of having combobox column, with an appropriate selected value, I just used textbox column.

Comment: I am glad you have a workaround. This is news to me as far as the first column being a combo box. That important info appears to be missing from the original question. But, if you got it working, then that  is all that matters.